# Isomorphism betweeen $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$

Tags: group-theory

The following quote is from *A Course in Modern Mathematical Physics* by Peter Szekeres:

> The factor group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ has just two cosets $[0]=0+2\mathbb{Z}$ and $[1]=1+2\mathbb{Z}$, and is isomorphic to the additive group of integers modulo 2 denoted by $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$.

The groups $\mathbb{Z }/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z }_{2}$ seem to be the same to me and hence are isomorphic but how can I show this formally?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, the "group of integers modulo 2" is precisely *defined* as the factor group $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that the function $f$ defined by $f([0]) = \overline 0$ and $f([1]) = \overline 1$ is an isomorphism from $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ to $\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: What does the "conjugation hat" means in this case?

Comment: Just that the element is a member of the integers modulo $2$.  So in general, $\mathbb{Z}_n = \{\overline 0, \overline 1, \dots , \overline {n-1}\}$.  This notation helps distinguish between $[1]$ and $\overline 1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ A ring $R$ generated by $1$ with characteristic $m$ is isomorphic to $\,\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z,\,$ by applying the [First Isomorphism Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Rings) to the natural image of $\,\Bbb Z\,$ in $R.$

Answer (score 1):

I think the Omnom's post gives us the idea, however; Bill's extended that. This below Cayley table makes the first post idea visualized:

[image]

Comment: Very nice table, B.S.!